# How to say to Phabricator to send mail directly?

Tags: php, email, phabricator

We are using Phabricator for our projects but we have a problem with the mails. We received the mail only hours after the updates. It's kind of under productive sometime...

How could I fix this? How could I say Phabricator to send the mail directly? I hardly find any information about the mail setting?

When I execute the command

`bin/mail resend --id whateverid`

the mail is queued but after 20min I still didn't received the email.

Answer (score 2):

We started seeing a similar issue recently.  We reduced the queue time by configuring more taskmasters.  This can be done by going to [Phabricator_URL]/config/edit/phd.start-taskmasters/.  We set ours to 6.  However, since we have our instance of Phabricator on premise, we updated the code to prioritize emails higher. To do this, we did this:

```
--- a/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorWorker.php
+++ b/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorWorker.php
@@ -9,7 +9,10 @@ abstract class PhabricatorWorker {
   private static $runAllTasksInProcess = false;
   private $queuedTasks = array();

-  const PRIORITY_ALERTS  = 4000;
+  // By default, PRIORITY_ALERTS was 4000; 
+  const PRIORITY_ALERTS  = 2000;
   const PRIORITY_DEFAULT = 3000;
   const PRIORITY_BULK    = 2000;
   const PRIORITY_IMPORT  = 1000;
```

Between these 2 changes, we haven't seen any email lag.  You could also change the type of priority Phabricator gives emails so they are higher